# Fastest way to convert a string into a Float32Array

Tags: javascript

How can I convert a string containing floats written out (not stored as JSON or something like that) into a `Float32Array`? I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
var str = "2.3 4.3 3.145";
var arr1 = parseFloat(str);
var arr2 = new Float32Array(arr1);
```

Comment: _Of course_ this doesn’t work, `parseFloat` will create at most _one_ number. Your `arr1` here is only `2.3` already, the rest got discarded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to split the values up, and then you can use `Float32Array.from` with the mapping callback:

```
const arr = Float32Array.from(str.split(" "), parseFloat);
```

```js
const str = "2.3 4.3 3.145";
const arr = Float32Array.from(str.split(" "), parseFloat);
console.log(arr);
```

---

Note: Unlike `parseInt`, it's safe to use `parseFloat` the way it's used above, it ignores all but its first argument so it doesn't care that it gets called with more than one argument by `from`. If you had to do something like this to create (say) a `Uint8Array`, you couldn't use `parseInt` as above because it would be confused by the second argument it would receive. In that case, an arrow function is a simple way to fix it (and lets you be specific about the number base as well):

```
const arr = Uint8Array.from(str.split(" "), n => parseInt(n, 10));
```

Comment: @user11914177 - No worries! BTW, unless you *really* need an array of `float`, I'd use `Float64Array` so it's `double`s. `float` is fairly imprecise. :-)

Comment: I need a `Float32Array` because the data is used by WebGL

Comment: @user11914177 - I thought it was probably something like that. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I like your answer, is there any advantage using from over map, like in my answer ?

Comment: @Cid - It avoids one of the temporary arrays (one in the above, two in your answer). Other than that, I don't think so. :-)

Comment: That should be really prefered, indeed, to use sequences instead of materialized arrays

Answer (score 2):

You can split, then map to an array of floats

```js
const str = "2.3 4.3 3.145";
const arr1 = str.split(' ').map(parseFloat);
const arr2 = new Float32Array(arr1);

console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```